# Is it possible to pipe() within a program in C?

Tags: c, io, pipe, pthreads, file-descriptor

Let's say that there is an existing program that listens on stdin for it's inputs. I want to create a pthread within the same program that is now the one to listen to stdin, and depending on what comes through, let it go through to the original program.

For this, I would create a pipe(), and configure the pthread to write to the input file descriptor, and the original program to listen to the output descriptor. Is this a correct way to have this done? I understand piping between processes, but is it possible to pipe like this within a single process?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can use pipe(), but the data has to pass through the kernel even though both the end points are within the same process.

If you have source code for this (which I assume you have) and you don't mind making non-trivial changes, and performance is a priority for you, I would suggest using shared memory to send the data to the original program. It will be much faster than using pipe()